# Rename MySQL database name using Query

Tags: mysql, database

How to rename `MySQL` **database name** using **Query?**

Answer (score 0):

You can't rename. You can create one like existing database.

```
mysqladmin -u root -p mypassword create newdbname
mysqldump -u root -p mypassword --routines olddbname | mysql -u root -p mypassword newdbname
mysqladmin -u root -p mypassword drop olddbname
```